# Return custom value from http service Angular

Tags: angular

All I wanted is to directly do like below in a component:

```
if(exampleService.checkValidityOfToken()) { //do something }
```

Below is the corresponding method in exampleService.Not sure if i didn't do return the proper way or I didn't retrieve the returned value in proper way. Can you please correct me on this?

```
 checkValidityOfToken(){
    let httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Access-Token': localStorage.getItem("token")
      })
    }
     return this.http.post(environment.tokenUrl,null,httpOptions).subscribe((res)=>{
       return true;
     },(err)=>{
       return false;
     })
}
```

Comment: Please use map or mapTo if you want to return custom value instead of subscribe, which can return those value to any consumers and one more u will not be able to use if like you mentioned above need to be handled asynchronously

Answer (score 0):

checkValidityOfToken method returns a **Subscription**, not correct to use it as a boolean, **you have to move the subscription from the service to your components where you are calling checkValidityOfToken, that will give you the possibility to do different side effects  on success**
if you want to get the returned value you have subscribe and //do something based on the returned value inside your subscription:

```
checkValidityOfToken(){
 let httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Access-Token': localStorage.getItem("token")
  })
 }
 return this.http.post(environment.tokenUrl,null,httpOptions); // this will return an Observable
}
```

and then you have only to call it in your component

```
this.exampleService.checkValidityOfToken().subscribe((res)=>{
   // do something 
 },(err)=>{
   return false;
 })
```

if you need it for your guard

```
canActivate(): Observable<boolean>{
    return this.exampleService.checkValidityOfToken().pipe(
      map(response => {
            return true;
     }),
     catchError((err) => return of(false))
    )
}
```

Comment: This is already known to me. I wantedly brought up such a case to see if there's a possibility.

Comment: And i subscribed and have been returning. why not it can be returned as required?

Comment: @Gayathri - You return a boolean from the `subscribe` callback method, not from `checkVAlidityOfToken`. As mentioned by @FatehMohamed, what you return from `checkValidityOfToken` is a `Subscription`.

Comment: I need to use this subscribe in a guard. that's the reason i see if there's a way to avoid subscription

Comment: canActivate() can return an Observable of boolean:  Observable<boolean>

Comment: i get "You provided 'false' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable."

Comment: Change it to return of(false)

Answer (score 0):

other proposition is  converting observable to promise with **toPromise()** function  and use **await/async**  like this

```
if(await exampleService.checkValidityOfToken()) { //do something } 


async checkValidityOfToken(){
    let httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Access-Token': localStorage.getItem("token")
      })
    }
     return this.http.post(environment.tokenUrl,null,httpOptions).toPromise()
}
```

Comment: No no... i donot require what response api gives. I just want to return true if i get proper response and return false if it is error.

Answer (score 0):

you can do the following

Before the constructor and in the constructor you put the following

```
public option: RequestOptions;
    constructor(private _http: Http, private envirment: EnvironmentService) {
        const headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8','Access-Token': localStorage.getItem("token") });
        this.option = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    }
```

You return a method in this way

You return a method in this way

```
MethodOfService () {
        this.url = this.envirment.Url + '/rulMetodoConsumible';
        return this.http.post(environment.tokenUrl,null,httpOptions).pipe(map(res => res.json()));

    }
```

And in the component you call it this way

```
this.variableService.MethodOfService().subscribe(
        result => { 
      // in the result variable the data sent by the service arrives
},
error => {
          this.loading = false;
          console.error('Guardar natural - ' + error);
        });
```